# Bootstrap Image over background image

Tags: bootstrap-4

How can we place an image over background image or how can we place a container div with text over a background image in Bootstrap4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<div class="container" id="imgbck">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
      <img src="yourimage.jpg" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
       your text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

css (parallax effect)

```
#imgbck {
background: url(yourimage-background.jpg);
background-attachment: fixed;
background-position: center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```